# How to access the mxL7704 through I2C on a CM4 (Compute Module 4)?

Tags: pi-4, i2c

From the schematics it seems the MXL7704 is connected to I2C0. So I tried to enable the I2C0 by putting this on `/boot/config.txt`

```
dtparam=i2c0=on
dtparam=i2c1=on
```

Unfortunately after a reboot I don't get any device on this bus:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# i2cdetect -y 0
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

What's wrong?

Perhaps the INT_SDA and INT_SCL are not connected to any I2C?

What I would like to achieve is to read the 3.3V which is not possible through `vcgencmd measure_volts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INT_SCL and INT_SDA are not shown as connected to the expansion header (as far as I can see).

Perhaps they are connected to one of the other I2C buses on the Pi4.

I suppose you could try writing drivers for those other buses.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the MXL7704 device on the Pi4 is managed by the Video Core and not accessible to the CPU.

It doesn't "measure" the voltage it uses an in-chip comparator.

The MXL7704 data sheet is readily available.

Comment: Are the BCM and the VideoCore two different entities?

Comment: The Pi SOC has 3 "components" the CPU, GPIO and Video Core which are relatively independent.